# Change Fargate ECS Platform Version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an ECS Fargate docker container which has platform version 1.4 and due to incompatibility with our setup, I need to downgrade it to 1.3 which would work for us.

[image]

What do I need to change in our configs or IaC to change the platform version?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what config / IaC tool you use but the theory is as follows: when you define a Fargate task the PV version definition is optional. If you don't specify it, `LATEST` is implied and `LATEST` resolves to a given PV at any point in time (we recently remapped `LATEST` to 1.4). If you want to have more control over what you are deploying, these tools allows you to specify the PV (again, syntax may vary depending on what you use). In your specific case I don't know if you specify `LATEST` or `1.4` (or you don't specify anything and it implies `LATEST`) but you need to tweak that parameter or add that parameter and set it to `1.3`. If you give us a snippet of your IaC code that creates the task we could be more precise on what you'd need to tweak.